# Replacement of AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

How do I port the following code to .NET Core?

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                new AssemblyName(
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Add this to your `project.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "System.Reflection.Emit": "4.0.1"
 },
```

and use:

```cs
AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

`AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave` is not supported at the moment - [link to source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Emit/AssemblyBuilderAccess.cs).

---

For new `.csproj` projects, use:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```