# How to dynamically add an instance method to type from loaded assembly in runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, reflection.emit, .net-4.8, dynamic-assemblies

I have .NET 6.0 app which dynamically loads .NET Framework 4.8 assembly. Calling method from this assembly with reflection throws this exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
> 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder
> System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName,
> System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.

By including a reference to System.Reflection.Emit, I found out that method `DefineDynamicAssembly` [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937276/replacement-of-assemblybuilder-definedynamicassembly-in-net-core) in `AppDomain` in .NET Core. Loaded assembly calls `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly()` and failing to find the method throws exception.

So I decided to add this new method dynamically in runtime and unsuccessfully tried two following approaches:

1. [The first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551452/how-to-create-a-method-at-runtime-using-reflection-emit) approach assumes defining a new method by [MethodBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) using [TypeBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethod?view=net-6.0) and [ILGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0). The problem is that I create an instance of `TypeBuilder` from `ModelBuilder.DefineType()` which defines a new type but I need to hook up to the existing instance of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`;
2. [The second](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/364544/Reflection-Emit-How-to-add-new-methods-for-an-asse) approach uses [DymanicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0). Unfortunately, this approach does not allow to create instance methods ([only public static ones](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/dynamicmethod.cs#L273)).

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Or maybe I am missing something in the above approaches? I will appreciate any advice!

Comment: _"I have .NET 6.0 app which dynamically loads .NET Framework 4.8 assembly"_ AFAIK it is very-very recommended not to do such things.

Comment: Consider if expando object is something you can use, because you control the assembly emitter, this supports what you want